# (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Arrow'

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have date parsed py python arrow library

and sqlalchimy filter

```
query.filter(EventFlight.departure_datetime <= arrow.get(params["date_to"]))
```

witch result in

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Arrow'
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ther are 2 ways to fix it

1)  in your model definition change date fiel class to ArrowType from sqlalchemy_utils

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import ArrowType

class EventFlight():
   ...
   departure_datetime = Column(ArrowType(timezone=True))
```

2) convert arrow to datetime

```
query.filter(EventFlight.departure_datetime <= arrow.get(params["date_to"])).datetime)
```

Comment: Option 3: write a psycopg2 adapter https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax